# Map is not returning the correct data type

Tags: javascript

```
 chew = '1235 51'.split(' ');
     item_id = chew[0];
     slot_go = chew[1];
     chew.map(function(v){
            return Number(v);
        }); 
console.log(chew);
```

It's on jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/jk939w26/

I'm trying to convert 1235, and 51 into numbers and not strings. When console logging chew after it's been mapped, it's still returning 2 strings in my array and not numbers. Not sure what what I'm doing wrong, hopefully someone can chime in, thank you!

Comment: Function is returning value, you should have to store that value in some var, and it will return you the exact value in number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array, it does not alter the source array, so you need to capture the returned array and use it

```
var newchew = chew.map(function (v) {
    return Number(v);
});
console.log(newchew);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/19xuuct1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 chew = '1235 51'.split(' ');
 item_id = parseInt(chew[0]);
 slot_go = parseInt(chew[1]);
 var array_chew = chew.map(function(v){
        return Number(v);
    }); 
 console.log(array_chew);
```

Answer (score 1):

Map returns an array. It is not working on the current array. Also it is better to use parseInt to convert string to number